# Artifact not updated when using mvn dependecy:get

Tags: maven, nexus

I can download a maven artifact using `mvn dependency:get`, but when the remote artifact is updated `dependency:get` does not download the updated artifact.

The `updatePolicy` from `settings.xml` is ignored.

```
<releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
</releases>
```

The artifact I want to download is not a `-SNAPSHOT` but a release artifact. It's version does not change. For the updated artifact I can see changes in the checksum for both the artifact itself as well as the respective pom.xml in the nexus repository manager gui. Seems like everything is properly configured since `dependency:get` and `deploy:deploy-file` work.

Is there any way to ask maven to check for updates on the remote repository?

```
$ mvn -version                                                                         
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_252, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.0-40-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven assumes that release artifacts never change.

If they change, this is usually some kind of mistake. One should not use the same version number twice.

You can call `dependency:purge-local-repository` to redownload all dependencies.

Comment: Maven does explicitly support this by specifying `updatePolicy` also for release artifacts. I agree with what you say when dealing with software artifacts like jar files. Your suggestion of using `dependency:purge-local-repository` requires a project to execute. I do not have / wan't to create a project.

Comment: It works fine with gradle using `resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'` by the way. I only wanted to try maven so I do not need to create a project.

Comment: But why do you have changing artifacts in the first place? How can a release version of an artifact change?